# How to add an external dependency from the above directory into the package

Tags: python, setuptools

## Current state

I have an external dependency on a **package**, and I have a problem with the proper definition of setup.py which causes problems with the installation of this package.

My file system looks like this:

```
/ 
└── home
    └── some_user
        └── dev
            ├── package_external
            │   ├── package_external
            │   │   └── __init__.py
            │   └── setup.py
            └── package
                ├── package
                │   └── __init__.py
                └── setup.py
```

Notes:

- I'm developing only the **package**,
- the **package** uses the **package_external** from outside of the **package** scope,
- the **package_external** isn't installed in the system, **and I wouldn't like to do this**,
- **package_external**'s directory (*/home/some_user/dev/package_external/package_external*) is present on all systems where the **package** will be deployed,

I have got a working setup.py file, which is similar to:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package',
      # ...
      package_dir={
          'package_external': '/home/some_user/dev/package_external/package_external',
      },
      packages=['package',
                'package_external']
      # ...
      )
```

Call

```
pip3 install .
```

from */home/some_user/dev/package* **works fine**. The **package** is able to use **package_external** sources.

---

## Target

I'm not able to remove absolute dependency to the **package_external** via strange path */home/some_user/dev/package_external/package_external* (its system file dependency)

After changing the line from **setup.py**:

```
'package_external': '/home/some_user/dev/package_external/package_external',
```

to

```
'package_external': '../package_external/package_external',
```

I'm getting

```
# ...
error: package directory '../package_external/package_external' does not exist
# ...
```

Comment: You have two `setup.py` there, and two different packages - why not simply using `install_requires`?

Comment: For some reason, I wouldn't like to install **package_external** as an individual step of **package** installation. Is there an option to invoke **package_external**'s setup.py from **package**'s setup.py?

Comment: No not really, well not without hacks. You could make them both packages of the one *distribution* though, that would mean moving `setup.py` up one directory (and only one `setup.py` file). This is actually quite common (for example the setuptools distribution itself packages "setuptools" and "pkg_resources").